# How do I convert a string to an integer given a radix in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a string that contains a number in the octal system. Now I'd like to convert this String to an integer. I found `text.parse()` which converts the string into an integer with radix 10. 
How do I convert the String to a number given a radix? (Ideally a solution that works for hexadecimal/decimal/binary/octal, and not only for octal)

Comment: [`from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.from_str_radix)